# Failed Lambda Function Deployment on AWS from PyCharm: Terminal Failure State Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pycharm

I would like to deploy a Lambda function on AWS from PyCharm on macOS. However, when I click on 'sync serverless application,' the synchronization process consistently fails with the following error:

```
Failed to create/update the stack: NAMESTACK, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: NAMESTACK, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

I have tried deleting everything in the S3 bucket, deleting all the stacks and creating new ones, as well as creating new S3 buckets, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen this error "User: arn:aws:iam::984272944563:user/gianto_new is not authorized to perform: apigateway:POST on  resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2::/restapis because no identity-  based policy allows   the apigateway:POST action"

Comment: I solved by add APIGateway permission